# time capturing in appropriate while doing conversation in morning

Tags: timezone, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

if I make conversations in the morning and say yesterday, it took **14 Feb 2024** instead of **15 Feb 2024**. I thought it may be a timezone issue if I do conversations after noon, it captures the date properly.

so my concern is how I can send the timezone to Google Dialogflow  so I can capture the **date timezone-wise**

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple answer to this is by setting the agent's timezone accordingly when initially configuring the agent in Dialogflow CX. Dialogflow uses the current time according to the agent's region. You can export the agent and then import it again with new timezone settings.
I hope I was able to address your question correctly.